# How should the [permanent] tag be eliminated?

Tags: discussion, tags

[permanent](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permanent)

It has apparently been used on only 5 questions. Two are for permanent-magnet motors and generators and one for a permanent-split-capacitor (PSC) motor.

I would be inclined to create [permanent-magnet-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permanent-magnet-motor) and [permanent-magnet-generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permanent-magnet-generator) tags. A single [permanent-magnet-machine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permanent-magnet-machine) tag might be better, but some people might not recognize it as meaning either a motor or a generator.

Would a [permanent-split-capacitor-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permanent-split-capacitor-motor) tag be too unwieldy? I suppose that anyone who would be looking for that might be just as likely to look for [psc-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psc-motor). Perhaps the [single-phase](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-phase) tag is all that is really needed, leaving the asker to give the sub-type as part of the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, tags like this are created by people typing in words in the "tags" field and hoping for the best.

The low usage indicates that we do not need a tag for any of these, it would be better to use larger categories such as [motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor) or [brushed-dc-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushed-dc-motor). Just edit as needed to get rid of the [permanent](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permanent) tag, and then the tag will be automatically deleted when there are no tagged questions left.

Comment: Sounds good. All edited.